# Calling nonmember instead of member function

Tags: c++

I have a very simple problem: Somewhere there is a function

```
int size (const C & c)
```

which is found, at least, by argument-dependent name lookup. Now the problem:

```
struct B
{
    int size () { /* ... */ }

    void doSomething (const C & c)
    {
       int x = size (c); // <----------- problem!
       // ...
    }
}
```

This does not work, as name lookup stops after having found the member function.

What do I have to write in the indicated line such that *not* the member function is tried to be called, but that, rather, the compiler does whatever it would do if the member function did not exist?

Note that the solution is *not* writing `::size`, as this prevents [argument-dependent name lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) and only works if I know where `size` is declared.

**Further complication:**

I know that for each relevant type `T` for which I use the below templated member function `B::doSomething`, somewhere there will be a function

```
int size (const T & t)
```

which is found, at least, by argument-dependent name lookup. `B` looks as follows:

```
struct B
{
    int size () { /* ... */ }

    template<class T>
    void doSomething (const T & t)
    {
       int x = size (t); // <----------- problem!
       // ...
    }
}
```

I want the non-member function to be called (which I am sure it exists, but which I cannot be sure about where it lives).

Comment: I take it renaming one or other of the size functions is out of the question?

Comment: Yes, since it's logically the same operation.

Comment: So you want a way to change function look-up semantics. I think the closest you can get is taking a seat in one of the C++ working groups.

Comment: Well, the question is: *Is* there a way to change look-up semantics already?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a well-known problem, and its solution is equally well known.  I'm surprised it has not been mentioned yet.  If you have a non-member function, such as this:

```
class C;
size_t size( C const &c );
```

You can make name-lookup find it in preference to a member function with a `using` declaration:

```
struct B {
  size_t size();

  void foo( C const &c ) {
    using ::size;
    size_t sz = size(c);
  }
};
```

When the compiler sees the call to `size(c)`, it starts in the innermost scope and searches outwards for something named `size`.   Without the `using` declaration, the compiler would have found the member-function in class scope before the non-member in the global namespace, but the `using` declaration changes this.  The innermost scope is the function itself, and the using declaration is found before the member function.

The beauty of this is that you still get argument-dependent lookup (ADL) because the actual call to `size(c)` is unqualified.  This means that you can use it in a template:

```
template <class T>
void foo( T const &c ) {
  using ::size;
  size_t sz = size(c);
}
```

... and even if the correct `size` function is in another namespace, it'll be found by ADL.  The `using` declaration simply needs to reference *some* `size` function, not necessarily the one you actually want.  It would be normal to have a default implementation somewhere that perhaps calls the member.  The next version of C++ standard (C++17) is almost certain to have a `std::size` function that does exactly that.  Once that is widely available, you'll be able to write

```
using std::size;
size_t sz = size(c);
```

At the moment, you can either provide your own default implementation, such as this:

```
template <class C>
constexpr auto size( C const &c ) -> decltype(c.size()) {
  return c.size();
}
```

... or you can continue to reference the version for `C`, and rely on ADL finding the right one.

Comment: That definitely is THE solution.

Answer (score 6):

If you can't rename your own member function, you can employ a dirty trick:

```
static inline int dirty_trick(C const & c)
{
    return size(c);
}

void B::doSomething(C const & c)
{
    int x = dirty_trick(c);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This pollutes my namespace with dirty tricks if everything has to live in a header file due to templates :-(

Comment: @JohnB: It's meant to go into a single TU, not in the header. Otherwise use an anonymous namespace.

Comment: @KerrekSB why not use anonymous namespace in source file too?

Comment: I do not get the point. Suppose `doSomething` is `template<class T> void doSomething (const T & t)` and `size` is `template<class T> int size (const T & t)`. Then both has to go into the header together with the trick and the trick necessarily causes pollution? Even with an anonymous namespace, I think.

Comment: @JohnB: an anonymous namespace never pollutes any other namespace, though, non?

Comment: Well, no, technically. What I mean is: If I write `namespace { template<class T> int dirty_trick (...) ... }` in a header file, then 1.) I do something which should not be done, as I should not use anonymous namespaces in headers, and 2.) `dirty_trick` is visible anyway after inclusion of the header, since it's one TU, so the anonymous namespace is useless. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @JohnB: First off, `dirty_trick` is never a template. Second, you can put an anonymous namespace in a header, and it'll create a different copy of the function in each TU. But we expect the thing to be inlined, so that's no problem. And yes, every TU's anonymous namespace has the function now, but not the global namespace. I think that's an acceptable solution...

Comment: Well, if C in my above example is everywhere a template parameter instead of a "concrete" type, then `dirty_trick` must be a template as well. And then I cannot use namespaces. I hesitate to edit my question.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, and adding to the accepted answer by Richard Smith:

My solution now looks as follows:

```
namespace adl {
   // This declaration's only purpose is the possibility to refer to
   // a non-member function named "size" in a using declaration.
   //
   // The signature does not matter, so we choose the easiest possible one.
   void size ();
}

struct B
{
    int size () { /* ... */ }

    template<class T>
    void doSomething (const T & t)
    {
       using adl::size;
       int x = size (t); // <----------- no problem anymore
       // ...
    }
};
```

This way I do not have to include any headers which might not be actually needed.